# Che cosa significa "giammai"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, meaning, single-words

Sto cercando di capire cosa significa la parola "giammai". Io vengo dal nord d'Italia e sinceramente non ho mai sentito nessuno usarla, proprio mai!
Sul dizionario ho trovato questo:

> 1 lett. Mai e poi mai: non lo farò giammai!
>
> 2 ant. Qualche volta, talvolta

Qualcuno sa se questa parola viene magari usata nel Sud? Devo intenderla come "mai e poi mai" oppure come "qualche volta"? Sono proprio confusa dal dizionario.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 11):

Nell'uso moderno, per il raro uso che se ne fa, significa esclusivamente “mai”, in modo rafforzato, specialmente in frasi dal tono sostenuto, magari scherzosamente («Non lo sposerò giammai»).

Non è specificamente un termine meridionale; anzi, molti esempi classici vengono dai toscani («Perch’ i’ no spero di tornar giammai, Ballatetta, in Toscana», appunto da una ballata di Guido Cavalcanti), da Leopardi («Spira nel pensier mio la bella imago, / Da cui, se non celeste, altro diletto / Giammai non ebbi, e sol di lei m’appago») e addirittura dal settentrionale Salgari («Se Negapatnan giammai tremò, il capitano Macpherson giammai ebbe paura»).

Comment: Si usa anche in risposta ad una domanda al posto di "mai" per dare un maggiore impatto. "Lo sposeresti uno cosi?" "Giammai!"